# Tilt animation makes img run the entire page

Tags: html, css, image, animation

First post. Started Coded 2 days ago. Don't go easy on me!

I literally copy+paste a code to tilt an `img` the problem is that it runs throw the entire web page until it lands on the desire spot (the right end of it). Now all I want is that the imag sits tight in that spot (NO ANIMATION WHAT SO EVER) until I jump my house on it and voilá, TILT!

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation tilt">
  <div class="face">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="/images/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Me" style="width: 64px; height: 64px; border: 0px"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="linked">
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="/images/linkedin-icon.png" alt="LinkedIn Me" style="width: 64px; height: 64px; border: 0px"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navigation {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 88%;
  width: 128px;
}

.linked {
  display: inline;
}

.face {
  float: left;
}

.navigation {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.tilt:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateZ(-30deg);
}
```

By the way, both images were getting on top of each other, the only solution that I found was to `display: inline` one and make the other `float: left`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is because the animation is run as soon as the relevant code has been read, which may be too soon in the process. To time it better, you would probably need to use a bit of JavaScript and apply the animated class to the element when *all* content has fully loaded. I see some insufficient prexing as well though.

Comment: @Shikkediel that's not true.  the :hover pseudoclass means the transition only gets run when the user's cursor is inside the element.

Comment: Yeah, might have jumped  the gun there with a presumption. ;-)

Comment: happens to all of us! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are applying tilt CSS to the *parent* of your images.  if you want only your images to tilt, then only apply the tilt CSS to those images.  so remove the `tilt` class from your div.navigation element:

`<div class="navigation`<strike>`tilt`</strike>`">`

and add it to each of your images:

`<div class="face tilt">` and `<div class="linked tilt">`

you must also move your transition CSS into the `.tilt:hover` selector block, otherwise your images will jump from normal -> tilt .

```
.tilt:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateZ(-30deg);
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms1-transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ohk9wa4c/

also, it is a little bad to `display: inline` one image and `float: left` another.  to stop your images from stacking, just use `display: inline-block` for both of them:

```
div.face, div.linked {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

(you will have to adjust the margin and width of `.navigation` for this to be successful.)

http://jsfiddle.net/ohk9wa4c/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Btw would you this kind of animation on another language? (and if not asking too much,vwhy would you so).

Comment: About the code, it worked properly the moment I broke the tilt into the div.face and div.linked. No more marathon's throw the webpage.
About the stacking I wasnt getting it at first because I already had a width="128px" on .navigation (each of the imgs being 64x64), but I changed it to 300 and they stopped stacking, not sure why tho.

Once again. Thanks! (edit time ran out)